# How do you name the columns in a HDF5 data set?

Tags: python, hdf5, h5py

I've made a data set in h5py:

```
f = h5py.File("experimentReadings.hdf5", "w")
dset = f.create_dataset("physics", (5,4), dtype='f')
```

I have a list of variable names: `namesList = ['height', 'mass', 'velocity', 'gravity']`.

I would like these variable names to be the names of the columns in `dset`.

At the moment, the columns just have numbers `0,1,2,3` as their names, like this:

[image: current data set with numbers as column names]

I would like this:

[image: data set with words as column names]

I suppose I'm looking for some code like this:

```
dset[:,0].column_name = namesList[0]
dset[:,1].column_name = namesList[1]
etc...
```

Whatever the solution is, it needs to handle the real data set I'm working with, where `namesList` is 280,000 words long.

Comment: `h5py` uses `numpy` arrays; they don't have column names.  If the array has mixed dtypes, you could use `structured` arrays, with named fields (not columns).  But you might want to use `pandas` dataframes instead.  It use `pytables` to save data to `HDF5` files.

Comment: @hpaulj Okay, my data set is 70,000 rows by 280,000 columns and all the data are floats. Will pandas work on a data set of that size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting question about dataset size. I have seen HDF5 files with 10e6 rows, but not 280,000 columns. You will have to test.

Regarding names for your columns/files, you can use a record array (as hpaulj explained). Use a NumPy dtype to define the names. I created some arbitrary data to populate my recarray, then reference with the `data=` parameter.

Give this a try:

```
# Create some data
data1  = np.arange(100.)
data2  = 2.0*data1
data3  = 3.0*data1
data4  = 3.0*data1

# use namesList to define dtype for recarray
namesList = ['height', 'mass', 'velocity', 'gravity']
ds_dt = np.dtype({'names':namesList,'formats':[(float)]*4 }) 

rec_arr = np.rec.fromarrays([data1, data2, data3, data4], dtype=ds_dt)

with h5py.File("experimentReadings.hdf5", "w") as h5f :

    dset = h5f.create_dataset("physics", (100,), data=rec_arr)
```

Comment: Very good, this certainly gives the columns names. How do you extract a row of data from this data set? I can get a column by doing `dset['mass']` for instance.

Comment: h5py datasets work _just like numpy indexing_. Just use the row index: `dset[0]` for the first row, `dset[-1]` for the last row, etc. this will return all the values in the row as a recarray. You can also use `dset[0]['mass']`. Pytables has some nice methods to find and select rows with conditional tests (for example `mass>5.` or `height<100.`)

Comment: Excellent. Suppose you wanted to delete a column..how do you do that?

Comment: I'm not sure you can delete a column/field of data from a HDF5 file with h5py or PyTables. If you can, I don't know how to do it. Sorry.

Comment: The `unstructured_to_structured` function, https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/basics.rec.html#numpy.lib.recfunctions.unstructured_to_structured might also be handy.