# Adding column name to h5 dataset using python

Tags: python-2.7, h5py

I am writing a 2d Array to h5 file using `create_dataset` function

```
arr=[[2,1,1],[2,1,4],[4,3,2]]

dset = hf.create_dataset("myarr",  data=arr)
```

But this file gets written with column names as indexes ("0", "1", "2")

[image: Here's the dataset].

But I need column names as "Age", "Count", "Years".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58999029/how-do-you-name-the-columns-in-a-hdf5-data-set This should help

Comment: `np.array(arr)` doesn't have column names, and neither does the dataset created from it.  How much `numpy` do you understand?

Comment: @hpaulj. I am very new to numpy and python too. How can we do it in pandas. I've heard we are able to achieve this using pandas.

Answer (score 1):

Convert to numpy array and then transpose it.

```py
namesList = ['X Point', 'Y Point', 'Z Point']

ds_dt = np.dtype({'names': namesList,'formats': [np.float64, np.float64, np.float64]})

my_arr = np.array([[2, 1, 1],[2, 1, 4],[4, 3, 2]]).transpose()

rec_arr = np.rec.fromarrays(my_arr, dtype=ds_dt)

with h5py.File("experimentReadings.h5", "w") as h5f:
    
    dset = h5f.create_dataset("myarr", data=rec_arr)

h5f.close()
```